# What are some information data structures?

Tags: data-structures

Most data structures are designed to hold data.
Data is something that means something to a computer.
Information is something that means something to a human.
What data structures are designed more for information rather than data?

Examples might include things like xml, .jpg, and Gray codes which all have an information feel to me.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a too broad question. Information is stored as data in many different ways but ultimately the way you interpret it will give it some meaning. For instance a word document written in Chinese will be stored as data and interpreted by someone who knows how to read mandarin.

If you are talking about information retrieval using AI techniques, that's another story, also very broad. So be more specific to help yourself.

Finally, the way you store data some times is related to the way they are represented in real life. An image, a matrix, note a tree for example. Some more complex information, like a huge DNA sequence, are stored in a way that is more suitable for computers (to speed up pattern analysis for instance). So there is also a translation from information (suitable for humans) to data (suitable to computers) back and forth.

That's why there's job for us!

Answer (score 0):

Books, newspapers, videos.

Media.

Information is data with a context.  The context has to be a part of the data structure to be considered information.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a good example.  Pretty much any office document format, many of which have at least an XML representation.  Charts and graphs.  Plain text files.

I'm not sure I would include .jpg, since it's not really a human-readable format.  You need a computer to display a .jpg for you or it's just data.

It's worth mentioning that just about any information is just the same... data arranged in a way that a person or machine can understand.